# Is this sentence gramatically correct: "A sub-reddit for questions, discussion and resource sharing on Indians' academics/admissions/education."?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

We have created a new sub reddit on Indian Academics, and are now thinking on the changes for the description to include even the abroad education questions of Indians.

We don't know complete grammar of English, and our user thinks this sentence as to be having grammatical mistake:

> A sub-reddit for questions, discussion and resource sharing on Indians' academics/admissions/education.

We are thinking on there being a mistake in this part:

> on Indians' academics/admissions/education.

Here is the reasoning given by the user:

> im not a specialist in Language/Linguistics so my understanding comes from use and convention.
>   so Indian is plural when used in the sentence "indian academics/admission/education" since it refers to indians as a people. Indian's would show possession but it would be incorrect to use "Indian's academics" since correct use would be India's academics. indians is plural but when used as "Indians academics/admission/education" the grammar is off since '/' is a substitute for and-or thus will read "Indians academics and-or research and-or education". thus right convention would be to have "on academics/admissions/education in India" or "on academics/admissions/education for indians.
>   Im unfamiliar with the convention of how Indians' is used.

We are discussing here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Indian_Academia/comments/8gmq61/suggest_the_changes_for_the_description_of_the/dyj6opu/

We thought, here we would know on whether the sentence is grammatically correct or not in least time. We are even thinking to have "regarding" instead of the word "on".

Comment: What is the mistake which is identified in that phrase?

Comment: Please make your question complete: don't bury important information in comments. Proof-reading questions like this are subject to strict guidelines (see the [Help](/help/on-topic) and scroll down to "How do I ask about checking my text?")

Comment: You should specify that you mean Asian Indians not American Indians, or just say that it's about Academics from India. Wouldn't want to confuse the Cowboys, now would we? :)

Comment: :) That would be precise. We will think on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I see it. Since Indian is both a noun and an adjective, your use of Indian s apostrophe dictates it to be a noun and that you are expressing a possessive relationship. Although it's grammatically correct, it is nevertheless less descriptive of what you are really trying to say, which I believe is 'academic of Indian descent' as opposed to 'academics who belong to Indians'.

And his/her second point is solid.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What description would you suggest for the sub?

Comment: I thought on having *Indian* instead of *Indians'* in the description; but having only Indian seems to eliminate questions related to abroad education.

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer I would suggest '...on Indian academics/admissions/education'. It reads like 'a place to discuss academics of Indian descent', 'admission in India the country', and 'Indian education' which means education of the Indian variety.

Comment: Having only Indian instead of Indians', seems to eliminate questions related to abroad education. We intend to have even abroad education posts too. What would you suggest here?

Comment: Abroad education from which point of view? For non Indians to india or the other way around? Either way, I think a general discussion on Indian education is all-encompassing. Otherwise I'd suggest adding education options, opportunities, or educational landscape.

Comment: Both, for non Indians to India and Indians to non India. "Indian academics/admissions/education", seems to limit posts related to academics/admissions/education in India. But, "Indians' academics/admissions/education", seem to allow posts of Indians' admissions to other foreign colleges too (as it mentions Indians' admission, and not admissions in India), and seem to allow other foreign nationals to post question on Indians' academics or admission procedures too.

Comment: I see where the confusion comes from. Indian as adjective means 'of, relating to, or characteristic of India or the 
East Indies.' so I think Indian admission will suffice. Again, Indians' admission means admissions owned by Indians, like Americans' right to arm meaning right to arm that belong to all Americans and americans only.

Comment: We changed the description yesterday; we will think on it again.